# Python 3.4.1, Tkinter 8.6.3, Event within class throwing 'Name not defined' error when looking for class button

Tags: python, class, tkinter, nameerror

I'm trying to set the state of a button to 'normal' after the user clicks on another button, but for whatever reason the event can't seem to find button I'm referencing and throws a `NameError: name 'rawButton' is not defined'` error. I've tried prepending the button with `self.` but then I get a `self not defined` error. I've looked all over and I can't for the life of me figure out why this isn't working... Thanks in advance for any help you can give.

Relevant code below:

```
import tkinter as tk
from imaging import *

class MainClass:
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title('Main Window')

    def call_bgFrame(self):    
        self.background = bgFrame()
        rawButton.config(state = 'normal')

    labels = ['Calibration','Background','Raw Data','Bin','Plot']

    calibButton = tk.Button(root,text = labels[0], width = 20, height = 5)
    bgButton = tk.Button(root,text = labels[1], width = 20, height = 5)
    rawButton = tk.Button(root,text = labels[2], width = 20, height = 5, state = 'disabled')
    binButton = tk.Button(root,text = labels[3], width = 20, height = 5, state = 'disabled')
    plotButton = tk.Button(text = labels[3], width = 40, height = 5, state = 'disabled')

    calibButton.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
    bgButton.grid(row=0,column=1)
    rawButton.grid(row=0,column=2)
    binButton.grid(row=1,column=0)
    plotButton.grid(row=1,column=1,columnspan = 2)

    bgButton.bind('<Button-1>', call_bgFrame)

    tk.mainloop()
```

Note: That `bgFrame()` function is one of the functions that was imported from imaging and is meant to return an array (using numpy).

Comment: You seem to have a very strange arrangement there; why on earth are you trying to run the whole code inside a class definition?! Note that the argument to `call_bgFrame`, although you've named it `self`, will be an `Event` not a `MainClass`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe honestly, I'm not too sure. I'm really bad with structure and normally I work with little scripts where it doesn't seem to make a difference, but now that I'm actually trying to make programs I found that I needed to make a class, but I guess I didn't really know how...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your coding style is very confusing. The problem can be solved by sticking to a more common style of coding: move the code into `__init__`, and save references to the widgets as instance variables.

```
import Tkinter as tk
from imaging import *

class MainClass:
    def __init__(self):
        root = tk.Tk()
        root.title('Main Window')

        labels = ['Calibration','Background','Raw Data','Bin','Plot']

        self.calibButton = tk.Button(root,text = labels[0], width = 20, height = 5)
        self.bgButton = tk.Button(root,text = labels[1], width = 20, height = 5)
        self.rawButton = tk.Button(root,text = labels[2], width = 20, height = 5, state = 'disabled')
        self.binButton = tk.Button(root,text = labels[3], width = 20, height = 5, state = 'disabled')
        self.plotButton = tk.Button(text = labels[3], width = 40, height = 5, state = 'disabled')

        self.calibButton.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
        self.bgButton.grid(row=0,column=1)
        self.rawButton.grid(row=0,column=2)
        self.binButton.grid(row=1,column=0)
        self.plotButton.grid(row=1,column=1,columnspan = 2)

        self.bgButton.configure(command=self.call_bgFrame)

        root.mainloop()

    def call_bgFrame(self):    
        self.background = bgFrame()
        self.rawButton.config(state = 'normal')

app = MainClass()
```

There are a few other things I'd change, but I tried to keep your code as similar to the original as possible.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I noticed you used `.configure(command = event)` as opposed to `.bind(button, event)`. Is this the go to method to bind events to buttons? I'm very new to making GUIs and all the tutorials I found said to use `.bind`. Also, what about the code is confusing? Not trying to be defensive, I just don't know enough to know when I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: @wes3449: yes. You should _not_ using `bind` on buttons unless you need some unique, non-standard behavior. To call a function from a button you should always use the `command` attribute. The code is confusing because you use lots of local variables, and your initialization code was in the wrong place. "Confusing" was probably the wrong word. Perhaps "non-standard" or simply "incorrect" would be better.

Comment: @BryanOakley Ah ok, I was told it was bad practice to use global variables so I guess I swung to the other extreme.. Thanks again.

Comment: @wes3449: It _is_ bad to use global variables. Using classes and instance attributes is a way to share information between related functions without having to use global variables.

Comment: @BryanOakley, gotcha. One last thing: I'm realizing now that I have a few events that simply call a function that doesn't return anything worth being committed to memory. In this case, can I just do `command = function` or is it still best practice to do `command = call_function` and `def call_function(): function()`?

Comment: @wes3449: There's no need to create a `call_function` function if the only thing it does is call another function.